# Programatically updating a VSTO Word Addin in IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7, vsto, clickonce

We have recently moved to a new web server (from IIS6 to IIS7.5) and I'm having some trouble updating our VSTO word addin.

Our app checks for updates manually when logging in and if a newer version has been found updates like this (let me know if there is a better way to do this - I've tried `ApplicationDeployment.Update()` but had no luck with it either!):

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Visible = false;
Uri setupLocation = new Uri("https://updatelocation.com/setup.exe");
browser.Url = setupLocation;
```

This used to launch the setup and update the app and when the user restarted word they would have the new version installed. Since the server move the update no longer happens. No exceptions are thrown. Browsing to the URL launches the updater as expected. What would I need to change to get this to work?

Note I have the following MIME types setup on the folder in IIS:

**.application**
application/x-ms-application

**.manifest**
application/x-ms-manifest

**.deploy**
application/octet-stream

**.msu**
application/octet-stream

**.msp**
application/octet-stream

**.exe**
application/octet-stream

**Edit**

OK I've had a look in fiddler and its returning a body size of -1:

[image]

If I enter the same URL in IE you can see that the setup.exe is launched without problems.

This is what fiddler displays in the raw view when accessing from word:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Sep 2011 15:07:42 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "9bd0c334277dcc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 07:42:18 GMT
Content-Length: 735608

MZ��������������������@������������������������������������������   �!�L�!This program cannot be run in DOS mode. $�������

*** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 128 characters. Right-click to disable truncation. ***
```

Comment: Have you tried a tool like (for instance) fiddler2 to see what http traffic is actually created? Does the client make a server call? What does the server actually return?

Comment: @Eddy I didnt even think of using fiddler to monitor addin traffic - good idea! I'll try when I'm back at work on Monday. Thanks

Comment: @Eddy I've had a look with fiddler and updated my answer above. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: The -1 body size together with the green down arrow in front of the row implies that there is no result received from the server. It looks as if the request gets dropped by the server or that the request hangs). You should compare the requests and see how they are different. (Possible relevant sidenote: why do you have backward slashes instead of forward slashes in "https:\\updatelocation.com\setup.exe" ?)

Comment: @Eddy Ok I've realised what the problem was - it was looking for the update in a location that was on the old domain, which is why it was failing on the live server. Your Fiddler tip helped alot so answer with that if you want some points :)

Comment: added it as an answer so this question can be marked as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a tool like (for instance) fiddler2 to see what http traffic is actually created? 
Does the client make a server call? What does the server actually return?

Then:

- Make the calls from within word (which isn't working)
- Make the calls by hand (which is working)

Compare both the request and response packages from those calls to spot the differences